# Why CodeIgniter with multi database difference hosting doesn't work?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my CI application i already connect with three databases db1,db2 the same database server host and db3 Oracle (on other host) all is work fine but when I tried to separate db2 install other host server it doesn't work. It always failed by produce **db1**.table_of_db2

```
            $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
            $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
            $db['default']['password'] = '';
            $db['default']['database'] = 'db1';
            $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';//MYSQL
            $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
            $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
            $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
            $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
            $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
            $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
            $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
            $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

            $db['ticket']['hostname'] = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
            $db['ticket']['username'] = "root";
            $db['ticket']['password'] = "xxx";
            $db['ticket']['database'] = "db2";
            $db['ticket']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";//MYSQL
            $db['ticket']['dbprefix'] = "";
            $db['ticket']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
            $db['ticket']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
            $db['ticket']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $db['ticket']['cachedir'] = "";
            $db['ticket']['char_set'] = "utf8";
            $db['ticket']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
            $db['ticket']['swap_pre'] = "";
            $db['ticket']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
            $db['ticket']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

My model:

```
$ticket_db = $this->load->database('ticket', TRUE);
$ticket_db->select('tku.firstname')
          ->get('tk_user tku')
          ->result();
```

With above active record it error by produce

```
SELECT tku.firstname FROM db1.tk_user tku //it apply db1 not db2 this error happen only difference host databases server
```

Comment: The problem should be in the model. Please show us the function you are trying to call.

Comment: I was edit sample code

Comment: I don't understand. In your question you say that you want db1.table_of_db2 then why loading db2 ?

Comment: db1.table_of_db2 I mean e.g. from above model query active record will produce 
  SELECT tku.firstname from db1.tk_user tku; but it should db2.tk_user tku